# Outputting Last Saved Date/Time to a Particular Cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to output to a particular cell (M38 for example) the date and time that a Google Sheet was last saved. I have this script, which automatically updates every time the spreadsheet is saved, but it does so on the last line. I can't figure out how to get it to appear in a particular cell.

```
function onEdit() {
  var thisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var theLastRow = thisSheet.getLastRow();
  var newRowRange = thisSheet.getRange(theLastRow+1,1);
  var theDateTime = new Date();
  newRowRange.setValue(theDateTime.toLocaleString());
};
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
function onEdit(e) {
e.source.getActiveSheet()
    .getRange('M38')
    .setValue(new Date()
        .toLocaleString())
}
```

Note that this will output the date (and time) in cell M38 (change to whatever cell you like) of EVERY sheet. If that is not what you want, you will have to check the name of the active sheet in the script.

UPDATE: based on the comments of the OP, a slight change in the code to meet the new requirements:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var d = new Date()
e.source.getActiveSheet()
.getRange('M37')
.setValue('Last Modified:\n' +d
    .toLocaleDateString() + '\n' + d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes())
}
```

Comment: When I try this I get the following error: "TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (line 4, file "Code")". Not sure what this means, exactly.

Comment: You probably ran it from the script editor ? Then the error is normal: this is an ONEDIT script: it registers an event taking placing IN the spreadsheet. If you are in the scripteditor no edits take place in the spreadsheet.Hence alle parameters of the event object (e) will be undefined. Just edit the sheet and see if the date is placed in cell M38.

Comment: Ah, yes! That worked. Thanks JPV! So would it be possible to add a line above that that reads, "Last Modified:"? And one last question, do you know of any way to split up the date and time. I.E. the Last modified line would be first, then the date on the line below, and then the time on the line below that. Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: Like: M37: "Last modified:" M38: date M39: time ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I would like.

Comment: Ok, great. I had those three lines (M37-M40) merged, but if I unmerge them it works perfectly. If I could keep those merged and perhaps just have everything show up in say M37 and use a new line for each one, would that be a possibility? Sorry to keep bugging you, but I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Warning, for where it matters: the onEdit() solution(s) apparently have a side effect on the Undo/Redo behaviour. Maybe worth informing your users about this.

Credits to &  more info at:
https://itectec.com/webapp/google-sheets-how-to-show-last-edited-date-and-user-on-google-sheets/

Comment: This should be a comment on the relevant answer, not a new answer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30073071)